# Is there any way to disable the notification sound on win10toast python library?

Tags: python, audio, notifications, windows-10, toast

I am using win10toast to make a notification popup for windows. Is there any way to make the notification silent? In other words, can I disable the sound for the notification I am creating? Can I alternatively change the sound?

Edit: added sample code

My sample code:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier


toaster = ToastNotifier()
for i in range(0,70000000):
    pass
toaster.show_toast("Hey User",
                   "The program is running pretty well. You should try to disable audio on me next though!",
                   icon_path=None,
                   duration=5)
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: @LucasHendren I added some sample code

Answer (score 5):

You have to modify the source code of the library in order to do this. Go to the folder where the library was installed and open "__init__.py" file. At the top, after all "win32gui" imports are put, write `from win32gui import NIIF_NOSOUND`.

After this, go to line 107 and you should see this piece of code:

```
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO,
                                  WM_USER + 20,
                                  hicon, "Balloon Tooltip", msg, 200,
                                  title))
```

After the "title" parameter, put "NIIF_NOSOUND", it should look like this:

```
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO,
                                  WM_USER + 20,
                                  hicon, "Balloon Tooltip", msg, 200,
                                  title, NIIF_NOSOUND))
```

If you want to do this alternatively you must further modify the source code, you can add a new argument to `show_toast` method. Something like this:

```
# line 121
def show_toast(self, title="Notification", msg="Here comes the message",
                icon_path=None, duration=5, threaded=False, sound=False):
```

And also further send the "sound" parameter:

```
 # line 130
 if not threaded:
     self._show_toast(title, msg, icon_path, duration, sound)
 else:
     if self.notification_active():
         # We have an active notification, let is finish so we don't spam them
         return False

     self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._show_toast, args=(title, msg, icon_path, duration, sound))
     self._thread.start()
 return True
```

Then also add the argument to the "hidden" `_show_toast` method:

```
# line 63
def _show_toast(self, title, msg,
                icon_path, duration, sound):
```

And make an if else statement to check if you should add "NIIF_NOSOUND" flag:

```
# line 107
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
data = (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO,
            WM_USER + 20,
            hicon, "Balloon Tooltip", msg, 200,
            title)
if not sound:
    data = data + (NIIF_NOSOUND,)
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, data)
```

This parameter expects a combination of InfoFlags that modify the behavior and appearance of a notification. Read more about [NIIF_NOSOUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataa#niif_nosound-0x00000010) flag and other flags. Here you can see which "NIIF" flags are available in "pywin32" [pywin32 documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html).

You can see more about the parameters of `Shell_NotifyIcon` function here [pywin32 Shell_NotifyIcon](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__Shell_NotifyIcon_meth.html).

The second parameter of `Shell_NotifyIcon` function is a tuple 
that represents a "PyNOTIFYICONDATA" object which takes different parameters, you can see more about this object here [pywin32 PyNOTIFYICONDATA](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyNOTIFYICONDATA.html) .

Note: This worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: worked perfectly thank you!